# c# data structure to use for string, <list> type data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Whats the best practice in .net/ c# currently for storing data fashioned from a string and list of strings?

The data is in the form of:

Site1 , list of strings (urlA, urlB, urlC... N'th)

Site2 , list of strings (urlx, urly... N'th)

Comment: Could you clarify and rephrase your question? It is totally unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> looks fairly good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is used as a lookup to the list of strings, you can use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` or `Lookup<string, string>`

Otherwise, create a small type to hold your data:

```
// or struct
class SomeMeaningfulName
{
    public string TheString { get; set; }
    public List<string> TheList { get; set; }
}
```